# KafkaIO withLogAppendTime vs withProcessingTime

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

In Beam documentation, it is recommended to use withLogAppendTime over withProcessingTime. Why would this be the case?

Comment: Depends on if you are doing historical processing, or not... I.e you get the current time you see the record, or you get the actual time the record inserted into the log

Answer (score 2):

As cricket_007 said, it depends on your use case.

One of the key concepts in Beam is event time processing. That is, you can define your data processing logic not in terms of when the service (Beam pipeline) receives the data, but instead in terms of when the event actually occurred (e.g. when a user actually clicked the ad). This helps in streaming cases, when your data streams can contain late or out-of-order events. Beam allows you to handle these cases.

E.g. if your pipeline has a step that does something like *"aggregate events that occurred between 1pm and 2pm on Oct 23 2018"*, what happens if an event that actually happened at 1.30pm arrives late (say at 3.30pm) due to some network delays or something else? In processing-time based approach this late event will probably be accounted for in the next window (e.g. "2pm to 3pm"). But there's a good chance that your business logic would prefer to recompute the original aggregation of "1pm to 2pm" instead of using the late event in another aggregation. Handling business cases like this is the main reason for event time processing.

However, you might not be interested in handling that in your business logic, e.g. if you don't do any windowing/aggregations (e.g. basic ETL), or if you don't have late data at all (e.g. when you're reading from an existing file), or your business logic simply doesn't care about it, or events are rare and delivery is reliable enough, or you might not have the reliable timestamp available to you in the event data, etc etc etc... So you might choose to use processing time instead. All depends on how your business logic needs the data to be processed.

Event timestamps are assigned close the event source in Beam (usually in IO), so in case of Kafka you have these options to choose where the event timestamp comes from: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/TimestampPolicy.html . Other sources can use other ways to assign timestamps to events (e.g. PubsubIO can read a timestamp specified in the message attributes).

I recommend looking through the presentations here, they go deeper into this topic: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/resources/

Comment: I don't need a convincing on Event Time vs Processing Time here as I am aware and making decision based on our constrains. That is not the ask. Either timestamp I use I am not processing by event time and in some systems this is a requirement.

Comment: It was not my intention to convince you to use either, but to explain the differences and reasoning behind them. It wasn't clear from your original post that you already know this or may have requirements to use a specific approach.

Comment: That said, I don't believe there is a deep reason to recommend event time other than limitations of using processing time similar to what I mentioned above. Either approach is perfectly fine to use for their use case.

Comment: Again my question is which of two processing time available by Kafka to use which is not answered here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question then. What is available in Kafka - I don't know, that doesn't seem to be related to Beam. In Beam there are few modes available, as you mentioned there are `withLogAppendTime` and `withProcessingTime`. The former is the event-time case where event time is set to Kafka's log append time for the message. The latter is processing-time case, where each record gets assigned the time when it is read.

Comment: However you can probably extend `TimestampPolicyFactory` to implement your own policy: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/TimestampPolicyFactory.html

Comment: There is also `withCreateTime`, see more details about these options here: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html#withCreateTime-org.joda.time.Duration-

Answer (score 0):

A couple of reasons to prefer event time processing:

You can redo the processing later -- for example, to fix a bug, make changes, or to test another approach. Being able to use the exact same code on both live and historic streams makes things easier.

Consistent, deterministic behavior -- if you run the same data through the same code, you will get the same results. This is not the case with processing time. Again, this makes some things (like testing) easier.